# How to use the merge tag for a RelativeLayout root?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a custom view which extends `RelativeLayout` and has its content defined in a xml file (has `RelativeLayout` as its root).

How can I avoid having two `RelativeLayouts` after the inflation of my custom layout?
I tried using the `merge` tag as my root at the xml, but that way I'm losing all my child views structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using the merge tag as my root at the xml, but that way I'm
>   losing all my child views structure.

I doubt that. The `merge` tag works with no problems, you just need to use the `merge` tag as the root of the layout file and assign the proper rules for the children in that layout. In the Eclipse's graphical editor this layout will not work(the rules will be ignored(quite normal as the editor doesn't know you'll use that layout as the content of a `RelativeLayout`)) but on an emulator/real device the rules will be applied.

If you have a sample application where the rules don't work with a `merge` tag don't be afraid to post it.