# Custom view: how to set the root layout

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to create a custom view (which extends RelativeLayout), which wraps a lot of other views.
I would like to create that child-views in a xml layout file. Now I wonder how I could inflate that layout and use it in my custom view. Something like this would be great (inside my custom view):

```
RelativeLayout rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(my xml file)
this.setContenView(rootLayout);
```

Unfortunatelly this is only possible in activities. Is there something similar for views?

EDIT:
I don't want to use View.addView(rootLayout) cause that adds another view hierachy, which is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to use the `<merge>` tag as the root element in your layout and inflate it in your custom RelativeLayout with `this` as the parent and `attachToRoot` set to true. You do not have to call `addView` then.

Here is a similar example with a [LinearLayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html) (bottom of page), should work with RelativeLayout [too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674559/how-to-use-the-merge-tag-for-a-relativelayout-root).

Answer (score 1):

Use the below

```
View v =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mylayout,null);
// inflate mylayout.xml with other views
CustomRelativeLayout cs = new CustomRelativeLayout(this);
// CustomRelativeLayout is a class that extends RelativeLayout
cs.addView(v);  // add the view to relative layout
setContentView(cs); // set the custom relative layout to activity
```

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="111dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

SView

```
public class SView extends RelativeLayout {

    Paint p,paint; 
    public SView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText("hello");
        this.addView(tv);
    }
}
```

In MainActivtiy

```
View v =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mylayout,null);
SView cs = new SView(this);
cs.addView(v);
setContentView(cs);
```

Snap

[image]

Edit:

If you wish to inflate in CustomRelative layout

In the constructor

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout,null);
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setText("hello");
this.addView(tv);
this.addView(v);
```

Comment: This way I will get an extra nesting level, which wouldnt be needed- I will have a relativeLayout (cs) and some extra root layout (mylayout), which will be nested. One of them is useless.

Comment: @stoefln so i may have misunderstood your question can be more clear or post some code snippets indicatign what you have done so far. One of them is useless no. in fact you can create a textview dynamically and add those to custom relative layout in which case you don't need mylayout

Comment: @stoefln `CustomRelativeLayout cs = new CustomRelativeLayout(this);` now you can create textviews like `TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("hello");` Now add textview to relative layout like `cs.addView(tv);`.No need for mylayout

Comment: Yes sure. But, as said, I dont want to create views in code. I want to use XML. But I dont want to have an extra nesting element which isnt needed.

Comment: As soon as you adding an inflated (stacked) view A via "addView" to view B, you have two views (A and B). One is useless.
In an activity you are "adding" the view via setContentView -> no redundant view is created in hierachy. My question was whether this is possible inside a view too.

Comment: @stoefln if you wish to inflate in custom view check the edit. But that's still nesting.  you add text view and then you add inflated custom view to relative layout. This custom relative layout can be set to activity

Comment: @stoefln pls look at figure 1 in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html. Anything you add to relative layout is a childview. relativelayout-->child1 textview and other views -->child2 custom inflated layout

Comment: yes I know everything you are telling me. The thing is: I was searching for an alternative. I want to "set" a view, not "add" a view.

Comment: @stoefln i don't know of any alternative i don't think its possible coz you add any child view to rootview it is another child of the root view.

Answer (score 0):

Within your view you can get layout inflater from the context, inflate children and add them to `this` (sub-class of `RelativeLayout`)

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, this, false);
// Then add child to this (subclass of RelativeLayout)
this.addView(child);
```

Edit:

The code above shows how to inflate children inside a custom view.
[This link](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr) shows how to insert the custom view itself into XML layout.